# Codeigniter/JS: get data from db

Tags: javascript, php, database, codeigniter

i have javascript in my codeigniter, which creates live graph. I taking data from database.
I need live graph, which will take data every x seconds from database, and draw it into graph.

I have this:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://www.gstatic.com/charts/loader.js"></script>
<script>
    google.charts.load('current', {packages: ['corechart', 'line']});
    google.charts.setOnLoadCallback(drawBasic);
    function drawBasic() {

        var data = new google.visualization.DataTable();
        data.addColumn('number', 'X');
        data.addColumn('number', 'Dogs');

        var options = {
            hAxis: {
                title: 'Time'
            },
            vAxis: {
                title: 'Popularity'
            }
        };

        var chart = new google.visualization.LineChart(document.getElementById('chart_div'));

        setInterval(function() {
            grepData();

            data.addRows([
                [prvni, druha]
            ]);
            chart.draw(data, options);

        }, 6000);

        function grepData(){
            <?php
            $vyber = $this->db->query('SELECT id, percent FROM cpu_stats ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT 1;');
            foreach ($vyber->result_array() as $row)
                {

            ?>
            prvni = <?php echo $row->id;?>;
            druha = <?php echo $row->percent;?>;<?php
        }?>
        }
    }


</script>
```

Problem is, query will take data once only. When i write second query in function, it will take data two times. When i delete query and write only `prvni++; druha++`, graph will working.

Sorry for my english.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`Codeigniter` is MVC (Model-View-Controller) framework. It is a bad practice to use database queries in View.

In order to plot graph points dynamically, you need to run `AJAX` every `X` seconds. `AJAX` will call a method in the controller, then controller will call a method in the model then the model will communicate with the database and return results back to controller, then controller again will return results to the view.

Answer (score 0):

Oh thanx. Now i got this

```
<script>
    $(document).ready(function () {

        google.charts.load('current', {packages: ['corechart', 'line']});
        google.charts.setOnLoadCallback(drawBasic);

        var prvni = 0;
        var druha = 0;
        function drawBasic() {
            var data = new google.visualization.DataTable();
            data.addColumn('number', 'X');
            data.addColumn('number', 'Y');
            var options = {
                vAxis: {
                    title: 'Vytíženost (%)'
                }
            };
            var chart = new google.visualization.LineChart(document.getElementById('chart_div'));
            chart.draw(data, options);

            function refreshData() {
                data.addRows([ [prvni, druha] ]);
                chart.draw(data, options);
                prvni++;
                //druha++;
            }

            function load_data(query) {

                $.ajax({
                    url: "<?php echo base_url(); ?>main/selectStats",
                    method: "POST",
                    data: {query: query},
                    success: function (select) {
                        druha = select;
                        refreshData();
                    },
                    error: function () {
                        alert("BAD");
                    }
                })
            }

            setInterval(function () {
                load_data();
                //refreshData();
            }, 1000);
        }
    });
</script>
```

When i use alert(druha);in success part, i can see value of that. But graph isn't working. When i will use druha++; instead of druha = select;, graph works..
Some tips for repair?

Comment: Now it's work. I used druha = Number(select);.  Thank you Abdelrahman Wahdan.